# Multiplying dataframe values with number of days of index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here in my dataframe and I want to multiply values of this dataframe with number of days of its index.

```
                     A         B             C                 X           Y  
date                                                                 
2019-01-31  198.882609   409.000    296.000000  ...   154.481481  113.444444   
2019-02-28  253.580435   237.200    179.857143  ...   161.858148  133.500000   
2019-03-31  295.650000   216.153    179.095238  ...   224.765556  144.888889
```

I mean, multiplying first row of all columns with 31,
multiplying second row of all columns with 28..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html):

```
df = df.mul(df.index.day, axis=0)
print (df)
                     A          B            C            X            Y
date                                                                     
2019-01-31  6165.360879  12679.000  9176.000000  4788.925911  3516.777764
2019-02-28  7100.252180   6641.600  5036.000004  4532.028144  3738.000000
2019-03-31  9165.150000   6700.743  5551.952378  6967.732236  4491.555559
```